# Highcharts put null values at maximum y position?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Setting a maximum of 100 for the y axis, any data point above 100 renders like the below screen shot. With the point being outside of the chart. Mouse hover still displays a tooltip showing the y position, in this screen shot it is 150 with a max y axis of 100.

[image]

I am setting null values for points, and connecting null values. Is it possible to reformat a null value and place it outside the chart or at the very least at the maximum y position? Below the null value would be May, is it possible to put this null value at the very top of the chart at the 100 line while keeping the value null?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't the 'connectNulls : false' option be better?  http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-connectnulls-false/

Comment: @BarbaraLaird no I rather not have a break in the line, i'm wondering if there's a way to use a formatter on null points and set them to 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could preprocess the data to set your null values to a high number and then add a tooltip formatter to display null for thoes values:

```
var data = [29.9, 45, 90.4, 29.2, 80.0, null, 24.6, null, 10, 12, 95.6, 54.4];
data = $.map(data, function (n) {
    if (n == null) return 150;
    else return n;

});
$('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {},

    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            if (this.y >= 100) return this.x + ':';
            else return this.x + ':' + this.y;
        }
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    yAxis: {
        max: 100
    },
    series: [{
        data: data
    }]
});
```

Comment: Thanks i'll probably use a variation of this

Comment: Can you take a look at this fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/peter/HVDyS/ why isn't Not found displaying on the tooltip for null values?

Comment: You had highcharts included twice (left hand External resource and in your html) http://jsfiddle.net/d3K6B/